# How to configure VPN per app in iOS 7?

Tags: vpn, ios

As one of the business feature the upcoming iOS 7, Apple has announced the ability to configure VPN on application basis.
However, details about this feature are hard to find on the web.
I am wondering, if this configuration will be something that can be done on the Device itself, or if it has to be something that has to be set up by an IT administrator in the network?

Comment: Once this is out of beta - we'll gladly reopen this. Until then - you can see the meta threads below for some options to get help in the interim.

Comment: @bmike Granted, it is in beta. But the information I asked about is something that Apple officially introduced and from the answers of the meta link you provided this means: there is no need to put this on hold.

Comment: Please edit in a link to Apple's non-NDA announcement and I'll gladly have a look at this. I've [started a meta thread to discuss this specific instance](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1790/) to discuss this specific question and whether it can work for the site before general release of iOS 7.

Comment: Why was this closed? Whether or not Apple wants it discussed is of no importance at all. There may even be potential answerers who are not bound by the NDA.

Comment: We can move the discussion about site operation to [meta] as Craig raises one of the reasons many people have stated they don't want NDA encumbered questions on the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I understand it. Mobile apps that run on iOS 7 can indeed be set up to (either manually or automatically) connect via VPN, but the devices have to be managed with OS X 10.9 as the backend VPN server and MDM. This is intended to separate the corporate connection (which may be carrying sensitive data) from the personal one.

Functionally, a payload (XML file) will be pushed to the iOS device. The VPN payload is designated by specifying `com.apple.vpn.managed` as the `PayloadType` value. The VPN payload contains VPN connection information, but relevant to VPN-By-App, the `OnDemandMatchAppEnabled` key is enabled:

> If true, the Per-App VPN connection starts automatically when apps
>   linked to this Per-App VPN service initiate network communication.

Additionally, there is a VPNUUID key:

> A globally-unique identifier for this VPN configuration. This
>   identifier is used to configure apps so that they use the Per-App VPN
>   service for all of their network communication.

And a SafariDomains key:

> This array contains strings, each of which is a domain that should
>   trigger this VPN connection in Safari.

So, the short answer to your question is **Yes**.

Comment: I wish it was that simple :).Identifier is com.apple.vpn.managed.applayer and beyond that even apple guys do'nt seems to have any clue how this works. Native iOS VPN client does not support it. My app keeps throwing error. "App layer VPN is required"

Comment: To clarify the response above, OS X 10.9 is not required to manage a mobile device nor is it required to handle the VPN. Per-App VPN configuration is handled through the MDM API's (Profiles). Thus, any of the MDM providers that can configure a device for Per-App VPN. The requirement is that the device is under management through an MDM system which can consist of an OS X 10.9 Server running Profile Manager.

Comment: While setting Safari Domains, I get the below error:

my-iPad profiled[2634] <Error>: MKBDeviceLockAssertion: MKBDeviceLockAssertion (asserttype:3)
my-iPad profiled[2634] <Notice>: (Error) MC: Could not add Safari App VPN rules
my-iPad profiled[2634] <Notice>: (Error) MC: Rolling back installation of profile

Comment: Old question, but would you know if you can whitelist specific domains in the perAppVPN - I guess via the payload?